# In R, subtract a value in one column from the value in another column

Tags: r

Pretty new to R. I want to calculate time durations, I have a start time column and a end time column. This is the code I have been using to try and do this:

```
modified_tds_merged %>% 
  group_by(Replicate, Stimulus, Subject, Attribute, Complexity) %>% 
  DistA=(start_time) DistB=(end_time) %>% 
  modified_tds_merged<-mutate(modified_tds_merged,duration = DistA - DistB)
```

And the data:

```
  structure(list(Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Stimulus = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Subject = c("S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", 
"S001", "S001"), Attribute = c("Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", 
"Soft", "Soft"), Timepoint = c(0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8, 0.81, 0.82
), Dominant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Complexity = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), start_time = c(0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.77), end_time = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But I get errors such as:

```
Error: object 'DistB' not found
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `DistA`
```

Comment: Ummmm .... in your code line 3, is it supposed to be a `mutate(DistA=..., DistB=...)`? (or perhaps `summarise(...)`. Otherwise, there is a lot of confusion going on in that code block ...

Comment: thank you, I used this and it seems to have worked `tds_merged_duration<-modified_tds_merged %>% 
  group_by(Replicate, Stimulus, Subject, Attribute, Complexity) %>% 
  mutate(DistA=end_time, DistB=start_time,duration = DistA - DistB)`. Do you still see problems?

Comment: I think it's odd that it's just copying `DistA=end_time`, are you meaning to do something other than copy two columns? Do you even *need* `DistA` and `DistB`, or can you just do `mutate(duration = end_time - start_time)`?

Comment: I see what you mean, yes I was copying a formula which used `DistA=` so I can do as you say. However it just subtracts `start_time` from `end_time` for every row and I only want the times when the complexity rating changed, do you know what I can add to achieve thta?

Comment: Yeah, Niamh, this is the first I've heard about "complexity rating changed", you're going to have to [edit] your question and include more context. While you're at it, please update your code (so that it's actually *legal* code, and it takes into account what we have fixed so far).

Comment: ... and since `Complexity` appears to be a constant `2L`, there's little likelihood that your sample data here will demonstrate the variability you need for your question.

Comment: I asked another question is that ok? It explains exactly what I want to do next for completion. Heres the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110967/i-need-to-apply-a-formula-in-r?noredirect=1#comment109852484_62110967

Comment: `complexity` is a rating of 1-9